# Source of PF 'anchor "com.apple.internet-sharing" all'?

Tags: macos, internet-sharing, pfctl

I see someone had/has the same issue I'm seeing [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/656877), but I can't find an answer to it.

**What I'm trying to do**: create a packet filter that is applied to any device that's sharing internet.  My use case has devices plugged into a Mac Mini via USB that shares the ethernet connection.

**What I've done so far**:

- Created a `/etc/pf.anchors/tethering` file with my desired rulesets
- Modified the `/etc/pf.config` file so it looks like this:

```
#
# com.apple anchor point
#
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
anchor "com.apple/*"
load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"

# Custom anchor loadings
anchor "tethering"
load anchor "tethering" from "/etc/pf.anchors/tethering"
```

- Run command `sudo pfctl -E -f /etc/pf.conf` to load modified config
- Run command `sudo pfctl -sr` and get the following

```
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*" all fragment reassemble
anchor "com.apple/*" all
anchor "tethering" all
```

- Finally, I test a device that's already connected and everything behaves as expected.

**What goes wrong**: Every time I connect a new device, my anchor appears to have no effect.  I run the command `sudo pfctl -sr` and get a different result (below).  OSX automatically appends an anchor *com.apple.internet-sharing* that overrides my desired *tethering*.

```
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*" all fragment reassemble
scrub-anchor "com.apple.internet-sharing" all fragment reassemble
anchor "com.apple/*" all
anchor "tethering" all
anchor "com.apple.internet-sharing" all
```

**Finally - the question:** How do can I find - and therefore modify - the `com.apple.internet-sharing` anchor?  Or, how can I prevent this anchor from being automatically added?

Thanks in advance for any and all assistance.